# How to get the tag_id link for the current country?

Tags: wordpress

How to get the tag_id link for the current country?

How can I get the link tag_id only for the current country, for example France?

When using get tag link(7) it return all posts in the tag relaxation for all countries, but I want to return a tag link only for the current country:

```
<h1><?php single_term_title('Country: '); ?>.</h1>


<h1>Relaxation Tour</h1>
<?php
global $wp_query;
$query = new WP_Query(
    array_merge(
        array(
          'post_type' => 'countries',
        'tour-type'    => 'relaxation'
        ), 
        $wp_query->query 
    )
);

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>

<?php endwhile;
endif; ?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link(8); ?>">tag Relaxation only for this country</a> <!-- How to get link tag_id only for this country for example France. Now it return all posts relaxation for all countries  ? -->
<?php

wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


<h1>NATURE</h1>

<?php
global $wp_query;
$query = new WP_Query(
    array_merge(
        array(
        'post_type' => 'countries',
        'tour-type'    => 'nature'
        ),
        $wp_query->query 
    )
);

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>



    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>

<?php endwhile;
endif; ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_tag_link(7); ?>">tag NATURE only for this country</a> <!-- How to get link tag_id only for this country for example France. Now it return all posts relaxation for all countries  ? -->

<?php

wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

[Attached is the image of the current state of the web site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AApoS.png)